# Set a property of each object of an array by default in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am declaring an empty array of objects called filter in constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       filter: []
    }
}
```

I am getting an API response which is an array objects something like below and storing in filter variable.

```
[    
    {
       name: "xyz",
       language: "english",
       age: 20
    },
    {
       name: "abc",
       language: "history",
       age: 21
    },
    {
       name: "efi",
       language: "geography",
       age: 20
    }
]
```

I was looking for a way where I can set a property like checked = false for each object in filter array by default in jsx file. Though the response from API is above, after receiving the response, the array should like

```
[    
    {
       name: "xyz",
       language: "english",
       age: 20,
       **checked: false**
    },
    {
       name: "abc",
       language: "history",
       age: 21,
       **checked: false**
    },
    {
       name: "efi",
       language: "geography",
       age: 20,
       **checked: false**
    }
]
```

Comment: `objects.map(x => ({...x, checked: false}))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using map and `Object.assign`, assuming `obj` is the respanse that you get from your api you can run the function below to parse your array an then set the respanse to your state

```js
var obj=[    
    {
       name: "xyz",
       language: "english",
       age: 20
    },
    {
       name: "abc",
       language: "history",
       age: 21
    },
    {
       name: "efi",
       language: "geography",
       age: 20
    }
]

var result = obj.map(el => {
  var o = Object.assign({}, el);
  o.checked = false;
  return o;
})


console.log(result);
```

Comment: even better would be `Object.assign({}, el, { checked: false })`

Comment: @Hamms yes it should work also

Comment: That will work. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Api.post(JSON.stringify(ConditionJson), AppConst.BaseURL + 'query/execute/conditions/LoyaltyStamps', (err, responseJson) => {
                    if (err) {
                        Alert.alert('Error!', err);
                    }
                    else {
                        var checked = 'false';
                        var name = responseJson.map(function (info) {
                            checked += 'false';
                        });

                        this.setState({
                            ischecked: checked
                        });
                    }
```